# "..sore trial to his.." seems incorrect. Am I right?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, pronouns

The passage from [the book:](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=VzeQQp7egJsC&pg=PA91&lpg=PA91&dq=%22Tom%20had%20been%20a%20sore%20trial%20to%20his%20for%20twenty%20years%22&source=bl&ots=-__c6qH6-p&sig=GSOzESrCpx6VG9U85t6Ujso9Uvo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjckc--3ZbcAhWMKo8KHe0DBcAQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22Tom%20had%20been%20a%20sore%20trial%20to%20his%20for%20twenty%20years%22&f=false)

> I suppose every family has a black sheep. Tom had been ***a sore trial to his*** for twenty years. He had begun life decently enough

I have problem at two places.

> *a sore trial?* It should be sore trail in this context. 
>  *trial to **his?*** or *him?*

Misprint? Mistake? or I'm missing it completely? :)

Comment: We answers questions here.  We are answering *yours* today.

Comment: It’s correct, but it’s also an oddly-worded phrase. [This ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sore+trial&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) shows the phrase _sore trial_ is a bit antiquated, but it likely would have sounded quite normal in the mid 1800’s. [This list](https://www.google.co.in/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%E2%80%9Csore+trial%22) is also worth a scroll.

Comment: @Tromano that example is completely different. Shoe me the usage of 'to' + 'his' without any noun or adjective.

Comment: Google wouldn't let me read the linked page, but the problem I have is that "to his" seems incorrect. It should be "to his (someone)" or "to him". BTW, you should include the publication nationality and date in your question, in case of dated usage.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the whole phrase is correct according to the meanings stated in the MW and Cambridge Dictionaries

[**sore**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sore) [adjective]

> causing emotional pain or distress

[**trial**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/trial) [noun]

> a person or thing that is annoying and causes a lot of problems

[**his**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/his) [pronoun]

> belonging to or connected with the person mentioned
>   *Isn’t this Kevin’s umbrella? I think it’s **his***

In the following phrases, this is remarked:

> Tom raced and gambled ...

Tom was the black sheep of his family causing them a lot of emotional pain during 20 years.

Answer (score 1):

*"A sore trial to **his**"* is correct. It's short for:

> Tom had been a sore trial to **his family** for twenty years.

The [Cambridge Dictionary website](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/determiners/possession-john-s-car-a-friend-of-mine) says:

> In short answers, we can omit the noun if it is not necessary to repeat it:
>
> A:
>   Is that your coat?
>
> B:
>   No, it’s Sandra’s.

This is that same construction, but instead of *Tom's* we are saying *his*.

Comment: Do you have some reference for this construction ("his"="his family")?

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/determiners/possession-john-s-car-a-friend-of-mine Go down to the *'Spoken English'* section.

Comment: The reference is in the prior sentence, @user3169.  The thing that's his isn't a "black sheep", since that represents Tom himself.  The next (and only other) available reference in context is "family".  Every family has such a person, and his has this painfully difficult Tom.

Comment: There is no "to his" on that page. Could you be more specific and edit into your answer. Since you wrote "to his" (by itself) is correct, there should be an explanation why.

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan I wasn't asking about the context, rather for some explanation why "to his" by itself without a noun is acceptable. I understand what was implied, but not why it was written that way.

Comment: @user3169 I added some more information into the answer.

Comment: Ah, I think I see your confusion now, @user3169.  You're reading "his" as a purely attributive genitive, but here it's a substantive.  This isn't the "his" that works like "my", "your", "her", "their" -- such that it wants something to modify.  This is the "his" that works like "mine", "yours", "hers", "theirs" -- such that it stands alone.  Check https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/his and see where it says "used without a following noun", or reference the second "for students" definition.

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan Some example sentences in m-w would have been nice. Anyway, while it might be technically correct, I wonder if people actually use such a construction. Since "his" refers to the family, "to them" would have accomplished the same thing. Possibly is this BrE?

Comment: The m-w example provided was simply "The book is his."  Anyway, no. "To them" makes little sense here, seeming to indicate something like "to all families".  The only family that relates to him in this way is his.  And, no, there's nothing particularly British about this usage.  My native and only language is American English, and using "his" as the lone object of a preposition like "to" is so natural and easy for me to understand that it was quite difficult to identify your confusion at first.  I don't see it as technically correct. I see "to his" and "to his own" as the only obvious options.